# How to list all the environment of Dialogflow using V2beta1

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm using the ["dialogflow"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) dependency for node js and I need to get the environment list for a given project in Dialogflow.

is it possible to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "the environment list"? Can you give an example of the results you're expecting or what you've tried that doesn't work?

Comment: In the Dialogflow console you can set differents environments for a chatbot. What I need to do is GET the list of environments of a given chatbot using the "dialogflow" module install from npm. I think it is possible using v2beta of the dialogflow module, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: ah! the image didn't come across for me when I asked. that is certainly odd. is the local environment you're running `gactions` in logged into either a GCP project (or have any GCP environment variables set) or a firebase project?

Comment: look this: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-versions

Comment: users can add multiples environments and then publish their chatbot changes to the environment that they want. What I need to know is how to get the list of environments using the npm dialogflow module that I mentioned before.